# How to create empty boxes at right page margin in exam class

Tags: boxes, exam, points

I want to create exams. Therefore I will use the [exam](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam) package.

How can I create emtpy boxes at the right page margin? I need this for adding up the earned points of each question.

My current document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[
%answers,
a4paper,ngerman,addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\colorgrids
\definecolor{GridColor}{gray}{.2}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{.8cm}
\extrawidth{2cm}
%Sprachliche Anpassungen
\pointpoints{Punkt}{Punkte}
\bonuspointpoints{Bonuspunkt}{Bonuspunkte}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{L\"osung:}\enspace}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{Aufgabe \thequestion.}}

\chqword{Frage}
\chpgword{Seite}
\chpword{Punkte}
\chbpword{Bonus Punkte}
\chsword{Erreicht}
\chtword{Gesamt}
\hpword{Punkte:} % Punktetabelle
\hsword{Ergebnis:}
\hqword{Aufgabe:}
\htword{Summe:}
%\thequestiontitle
%\qformat{\textbf{Aufgabe \thequestion} \hfill \quad(\thepoints / \makebox[1cm]{\hrulefill})}
%\pointsinrightmargin
%\pointsinmargin
%\boxedpoints
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Layout
\newcommand{\Lehrer}{\textbf{Hr. Hauser}}
\newcommand{\fach}{\textbf{Bauelemente}}
\newcommand{\Titel}{\textbf{1. Stegreifaufgabe im Lernfeld}}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
%\firstpageheadrule
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheader{\large\bfseries \Titel \\ \fach}
{}
{
  \textbf{\normalsize{Punkte: \fbox{\rule{1.cm}{0pt}\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{1.cm}}}}
  \textbf{\normalsize{Note: }}\fbox{\rule{1.cm}{0pt}\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{1.cm}}
}
\runningheader{}{\Titel{} \fach}{}
\firstpagefooter{}
{\vspace{2ex}\thepage\,/\,\numpages}
{\vspace{2ex} \makebox[1cm]{\hrulefill} / $\sum$ \pointsonpage{\thepage} }
\firstpagefootrule
%\extrafootheight{1cm}
\runningfootrule
\runningfooter{}
{\vspace{2ex}\thepage\,/\,\numpages}
{\vspace{2ex} \makebox[1cm]{\hrulefill} / $\sum$ \pointsonpage{\thepage} }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
%
\makebox[\textwidth]{Vor- und Nachname: \dotfill\rule[1ex]{0pt}{.1cm}}
\makebox[.5\textwidth]{Klasse:\dotfill\rule[1ex]{0pt}{.7cm}}
\makebox[.5\textwidth]{Datum:\dotfill\rule[1ex]{0pt}{.7cm}}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\parbox{6in}{\footnotesize
  \vspace{.5ex}
  \textbf{Erlaubte Hilfsmittel:} Taschenrechner, Tabellenbuch\\
  Alle Ergebnisse sind, sofern nicht anders angegeben, auf zwei Stellen nach dem Komma zu runden.\\ 
  \textbf{M\"ogliche Gesamtpunktezahl:} \numpoints{} \points
}}
\end{center}
\hrule

\begin{questions}
\question Berechne das Ergebnis von $1+1$.
\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
\end{question}

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\parbox{4cm}{
  \centering
  \vspace{.5ex}
 \bctrefle \textbf{Viel Erfolg!}
}}
\end{center}
      \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! - Does  [framed or colored box with text and margin notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179287/124842)  help?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

Note: `\linewidth` is the amount of space left after the environment is done indenting.  `\dimen0` - `\dimen9` are unused by LaTeX, but is still safer to make changes local (hence `\bgroup` ... `\egroup`).  The `\raisebox` aligns the bottom of the `\fbox` to the baseline.

```
\documentclass[
%answers,
a4paper,ngerman,addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\colorgrids
\definecolor{GridColor}{gray}{.2}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{.8cm}
\extrawidth{2cm}
%Sprachliche Anpassungen
\pointpoints{Punkt}{Punkte}
\bonuspointpoints{Bonuspunkt}{Bonuspunkte}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{L\"osung:}\enspace}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{Aufgabe \thequestion.}}

\chqword{Frage}
\chpgword{Seite}
\chpword{Punkte}
\chbpword{Bonus Punkte}
\chsword{Erreicht}
\chtword{Gesamt}
\hpword{Punkte:} % Punktetabelle
\hsword{Ergebnis:}
\hqword{Aufgabe:}
\htword{Summe:}
%\thequestiontitle
%\qformat{\textbf{Aufgabe \thequestion} \hfill \quad(\thepoints / \makebox[1cm]{\hrulefill})}
%\pointsinrightmargin
%\pointsinmargin
%\boxedpoints
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Layout
\newcommand{\Lehrer}{\textbf{Hr. Hauser}}
\newcommand{\fach}{\textbf{Bauelemente}}
\newcommand{\Titel}{\textbf{1. Stegreifaufgabe im Lernfeld}}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
%\firstpageheadrule
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheader{\large\bfseries \Titel \\ \fach}
{}
{
  \textbf{\normalsize{Punkte: \fbox{\rule{1.cm}{0pt}\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{1.cm}}}}
  \textbf{\normalsize{Note: }}\fbox{\rule{1.cm}{0pt}\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{1.cm}}
}
\runningheader{}{\Titel{} \fach}{}
\firstpagefooter{}
{\vspace{2ex}\thepage\,/\,\numpages}
{\vspace{2ex} \makebox[1cm]{\hrulefill} / $\sum$ \pointsonpage{\thepage} }
\firstpagefootrule
%\extrafootheight{1cm}
\runningfootrule
\runningfooter{}
{\vspace{2ex}\thepage\,/\,\numpages}
{\vspace{2ex} \makebox[1cm]{\hrulefill} / $\sum$ \pointsonpage{\thepage} }

\newcommand{\emptybox}[2]% #1=width, #2=height
{\bgroup
  \dimen0=\dimexpr #1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax
  \dimen1=\dimexpr #2-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax
  \raisebox{\dimexpr \depth+\fboxsep+\fboxrule}[0pt]{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\dimen1}\rule{\dimen0}{0pt}}}%
\egroup}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
%
\makebox[\textwidth]{Vor- und Nachname: \dotfill\rule[1ex]{0pt}{.1cm}}
\makebox[.5\textwidth]{Klasse:\dotfill\rule[1ex]{0pt}{.7cm}}
\makebox[.5\textwidth]{Datum:\dotfill\rule[1ex]{0pt}{.7cm}}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\parbox{6in}{\footnotesize
  \vspace{.5ex}
  \textbf{Erlaubte Hilfsmittel:} Taschenrechner, Tabellenbuch\\
  Alle Ergebnisse sind, sofern nicht anders angegeben, auf zwei Stellen nach dem Komma zu runden.\\ 
  \textbf{M\"ogliche Gesamtpunktezahl:} \numpoints{} \points
}}
\end{center}
\hrule

\begin{questions}
\question Berechne das Ergebnis von $1+1$.\\
\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-\columnsep}{\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}}\hfill
\emptybox{2cm}{2cm}
\end{questions}

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\parbox{4cm}{
  \centering
  \vspace{.5ex}
 \bctrefle \textbf{Viel Erfolg!}
}}
\end{center}
      \end{document}
```